# Recurrence relations and divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

A sequence is defined as follows:

$$u_1 = 1$$

$$u_n = (n-1) u_{n-1} + 1$$

How do I even approach the following question :

> For which values of n is $u_n$ divisible by $n$. Include a proper proof

Comment: Have you calculated some values of the recurrence? Do you have any guesses as to which $n | u_n$ ?

Comment: @Nitin I have calculated up to u<sub>8</sub>. I have a couple of pages of working out however I assumed polluting the question with them won't help. I can include them?

Comment: No need to include the calculations but maybe post the values of $n$ for which $n$ divides $u_n$.

Comment: We have the formula $u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{k!}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By actual calculation the first $6$ values of $n$ such that $n\mid u_n$ are $1,2,4,5,10$, and $13$. Submitting this sequence to OEIS brings five returns, one of which is the desired sequence: this is [OEIS A064383](http://oeis.org/A064383). (The sequence $\langle u_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is [OEIS A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522) with the index offset by $1$.)

It’s not hard to show by induction that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k!}=\frac{u_n}{(n-1)!}\;.\tag{1}$$

Then

$$u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{\ell=1}^k(n-\ell)\equiv\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^kk!\pmod{n}\;,$$

where $\prod_{\ell=1}^0(n-\ell)=1$, so the indices $n$ such that $n\mid u_n$ are the positive integers $n$ such that $n$ divides

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^kk!\;.$$

There’s a little more information in the OEIS entry and the references there.

**Added:** One might discover $(1)$ by ‘unwinding’ the recurrence for the $u_n$:

$$\begin{align*}
u_n&=(n-1)u_{n-1}+1\\
&=(n-1)(n-2)u_{n-2}+(n-1)+1\\
&=(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)u_{n-3}+(n-1)(n-2)+(n-1)+1\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=(n-1)^{\underline k}u_{n-k}+\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(n-1)^{\underline\ell}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=(n-1)!u_1+\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-2}(n-1)^{\underline\ell}\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}(n-1)^{\underline\ell}\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-\ell)!}\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{\ell!}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How would you deduce this forula without OEIS

Comment: @Bula: I’ve added a bit showing how one might discover the closed form for the numbers $u_n$.